# Javascript для сайта

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Хочу начать украшать сайт эффектами, ajax и прочими нужными вещами. Посоветовали jquery, но она както тяжеловата. Есть ли полегче фреймворк? MooTools не подойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery нормальная либа. Точно говорю. UI - да, тяжеловат.
Единственные ограничения: Опера 9.5+, ИЕ 7+(лучше 9), FF 4+, Safari 4+...
В старых браузерах производительности яваскрипта уделялось мало внимания

Comment: jQuery-UI можно подключать с необходимым функционалом, поэтому тоже не так смертельно, как кажется.

Comment: можно. Но для этого надо четко понимать свои желания.

Comment: Меня просто напрягают их копирайты. Это не может как либо вылиться во чтото плохое? Просто Яндекс я заметил тоже на ней работает.

Comment: Давайте разграничим копирайты, тяжесть библиотеки и тяжесть изучения.
Первое - что-то типа гну-гпл(прочитайте на сайте: любая версия, которая УЖЕ выпущена под этими лицензиями отозвана быть не может)
Второе - как правильно заметил metazet, - используйте только то что нужно.
Третье - у джиквери лучший сайт среди всех библиотек яваскрипт

Comment: Уговорили) Пойду изучать и начну пробовать. Но думаю вопросы по поводу использования всетаки возникнут.

Comment: Собственно мне нужно будет сделать асинхронную отправку формы post запросом и проверку данных при регистрации (email и правильность).

Answer (score 1):

О весе JQuery можете не беспокоится, действительно вес не смертельный, другое дело, что нежелательно подгружать 100500 дополнений к нему, как очень любят делать очень многие разработчики, вот на это действительно может уходить немало времени.

Т.е. если у вас, например, к странице подключается jquery, jquery-ui и еще, например, 2-3 дополнения, то для улучшения производительности лучше всего все посливать в один файл. Я, конечно, не знаю, какого уровня ваш сайт, но если корпоративный, то 100% надо делать именно так.

PS: Скажу честно: имея 2-ух опыт JavaScript разработки, реальных преимуществ от использования JQuery не вижу, юзаю, только тогда когда пишу JS в команде и то только потому, что так удобнее коллегам.

Comment: Просто свободно яваскриптом я не владею, а на jquery есть примеры реализации.

Answer (score 1):

> Посоветовали jquery, но она както тяжеловата.

Если нет знаний в JS то любой FW будет тяжеловат. Ничего сложного нету, препятствие только лень.

Answer (score 0):

Если тяжеловата в освоении, то даже затрудняюсь что-либо посоветовать, более легкое. По поводу же объема jquery production - 32 кб всего, что для современных скоростей вообще безвесная, с учетом, что подгружаются картинки под мегабайт. )

Answer (score 0):

90 Кб - это не много.(столько весит ужатая последняя версия). Mootools я бы не советовал по двум причинам:

1. Порог вхождения выше чем у jQuery.
2. Он изменяет прототип Object, лично меня это напрягает.

Answer (score 0):

Подробно описано, как использовать JQ тут: [jQuery для начинающих](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/). Более подробно нигде не читал.